# mysql replication user privileges

Tags: mysql, replication, privileges

I'm running a script and I get this log:

[2018/08/12 05:00:35] [error] canal.go:216 canal start sync binlog err: start sync replication at binlog (, 0) error ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'abcerca'@'%' (using password: YES)
[2018/08/12 05:00:35] [error] river.go:299 start canal err start sync replication at binlog (, 0) error ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'abcerca'@'%' (using password: YES)

He tells me access denied because the user has no replication privilege in MySQL.

How can I make the user 'abcerca' with this privilege?

Comment: The user needs the `REPLICATION SLAVE` privilege. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-howto-repuser.html

Comment: So the solution is:mysql> 
mysql> GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'abcerca'@'%.example.com';